# How to register multiple models with the admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

If I want to register my models with the admin I have to do this like this:

```
#admin.py
admin.site.register(models.About)
```

But with multiple models you **can't** do something like this:

```
models = (models.Project, models.Client, models.About)
for m in models:
   admin.site.register(m)
```

First of all: why not!? Secondly: imagine one has a lot of models which all should be accessible from the admin interface. How do you do that in a generic way?

Comment: You can in fact iterate over a list of models and do `admin.site.register(m)` - the example code above works (except that there is bad indentation).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`admin.site.register` has this definition in the library:

```
def register(self, model_or_iterable, admin_class=None, **options):
```

so models to be registered can be a single model or iterable object so just use this:

```
myModels = [models.Project, models.Client, models.About]  # iterable list
admin.site.register(myModels)
```

I tested this in my site and works perfectly fine.

Comment: Works fine in Django 2.1

Answer (score 7):

```
# File: admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Project, Client, About

admin.register(Project, Client, About)(admin.ModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Tested on Django 1.8,. Should work on other Django version >=1.7.

Comment: @Ben [`admin.register`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/contrib/admin/decorators/#register)  decorator is just a pure Python function anyway, and you can call it directly. [Python Decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator) is a function that return another function. And its syntax is merely syntactic sugar and they are semantically equivalent [as the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004665/764592)

Answer (score 6):

With respect to the recent release of Django 1.7, you can use the [`django.contrib.admin.register`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.register) decorator to register multiple models that using the same admin class.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Project, Client, About

@admin.register(Project, Client, About)
class DefaultAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

#### Update

Consider [making a simple call instead of declaring a dummy class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31568419/764592)

Answer (score 4):

Based on the snippet [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2066/), what I usually do is have the following code in my `admin.py`

```
from django.db.models import get_models, get_app
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AlreadyRegistered

def autoregister(*app_list):
    for app_name in app_list:
        app_models = get_app(app_name)
        for model in get_models(app_models):
            try:
                admin.site.register(model)
            except AlreadyRegistered:
                pass

autoregister('myapp')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is better way to regestering multiple models

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Course, Category

admin.site.register(Course)
admin.site.register(Category)
```

Answer (score 2):

With Django 3.1.3
in admin.py

```
from .models import Course, Category

admin.site.register(Course)
admin.site.register(Category)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import *


@admin.register(Project, Client, About)
class AppAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Comment: [Note that in general the practice of importing `*` from a module or package is frowned upon](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a wrokaround that attempts to register a custom models to the admin UI if existing else the default one, for that to work, you must follow the convention of naming your custom admin classes as "MyModelAdmin" by appending "Admin" to the end.

```
for model_name, model in apps.get_app_config('myapp').models.items() :
    if      '_' not in model_name   :
        if      globals().get(model.__name__+'Admin')   :
            admin.site.register(model, globals().get(model.__name__+'Admin'))
        else                                        :
            admin.site.register(model)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.contrib import admin

models = apps.get_models()

for model in models:
    try:
        admin.site.register(model)
    except admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.apps import apps

models = apps.get_containing_app_config("your_app_name").get_models()

for model in models:
    try:
        admin.site.register(model)
    except admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered:
        pass
```

Comment: what does this code do? how does it answer the question? Please clarify

Comment: it register for every models in "models.py" of "your_app_name"